# filter dataframe based on a condition on two columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i would like to filter a dataframe through two special cloumns, i need to verify that the take data should contain "range_id" from the dataframe range_id_Test and also  "family_id" from the datframe familyid_Test.

```
  val range_id_Test = newArticlesGold.select("range_id").except(article_ranges.select("id").distinct())

    val familyid_Test = newArticlesGold.select("family_id").except(article_family.select("id").distinct())

    val addedData = newArticlesGold.filter($"range_id" === range_id_Test("range_id") || $"family_id" === familyid_Test("family_id"))
```

Here is the sample of data

Range_Test

```
   |range_id|
    +--------+
    |      -1|
    +--------+
```

Family_test

```
|family_id|
+---------+
|       -1|
+---------+
```

and the newArticlesGold

```
 +-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---+------+------+--------+---+--------+---------+
    |CODEARTICLE|STRUCTURE    |DES                                               |TYPEMARK|TYP|IMPLOC|MARQUE|GAMME   |TAR|range_id|family_id|
    +-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---+------+------+--------+---+--------+---------+
    |662180137  |1173201099902|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|2       |9  |Local |      |        |   |1173    |1173201  |
    |662180717  |1173201099902|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|2       |9  |Local |      |        |   |1173    |1173201  |
    |435160050  |1443609010306|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|7       |7  |Local |      |60900010|   |1443    |1443609  |
    |435160060  |1443609010306|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|7       |7  |Local |      |60900010|   |1443    |1443609  |
    |553260040  |1428659020203|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|7       |7  |Local |      |        |   |-1   |-1  |
    +-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---+------+------+--------+---+--------+---------+
```

i want to get rid of the last rows
Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: I guess you cannot use two dataframes in filter unless you join them.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan ok ,any help i would like to filter  from that dataframe newArticlesGold the rows that have range_id in the dataframe range_id_Test  or family_id that exists in the dataframe family_Test , any help thanks

Comment: You have to use `join`. Can you add sample data and list expected output. You are excluding rows with `except`, but then in you `filter` operation it looks like you actually don't want it excluded, if it is present in one of the dataframes..??

Comment: the solution i am thinking right now is a bit complicated. you left join newArticlesGold with range_id_Test for $"range_id" === range_id_Test("range_id") and then you left join newArticlesGold with familyid_Test for $"family_id" === familyid_Test("family_id") and finally you union both the dataframes and drop duplicates.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt check the update thanks

Comment: But do you want to get rid of the line if _both_ of the `range_id` and the `family_id` are -1 or do you want to get rid of the line if _either_ the `range_id` or the `family_id` is -1?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt it is or condition wheither the first condition or the second , in both case i need to drop the row

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to do a kind of "nested looping" but that is not allowed in Spark. Instead, you need to use `join`. Like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val range_id_Test = newArticlesGold
  .select('range_id as "r_id")
  .except(article_ranges.select("id").distinct())

val familyid_Test = newArticlesGold
  .select('family_id as "f_id")
  .except(article_family.select("id").distinct())

val excludedData = newArticlesGold
  .join(range_id_Test, 'range_id === 'r_id)
  .join(familyid_Test, 'family_id === 'f_id)
  .drop("r_id", "f_id")

val result = newArticlesGold.except(excludedRows)
```

Comment: thanks , i just to want to ask whether this allows me to test with an or , other thing , now how can i get the new data from the table newArticlesGold excluding the filtered data ? thanks

Comment: ?? I don't understand your question. `FilteredData` contains the original data minus the rows where `range_id` is in `range_id_Test` or `family_id` is in `family_id_Test`.

Comment: , for me filteredData , contains the row , that need to be droped not the wanted data which is the whole data minus , the ones i i checked , , i need to find the size of intial minus 1 but i got as a result one row the one that need to be deleted did you understand me ? thanks

Comment: No, it contains the data WITHOUT the unwanted data.

Comment: The unwanted data is excluded by the calls to `except` when you generate `range_id_Test` and `family_id_Test`

Comment: ok ! i think you got me wrong so range_id_Test contains the range_id that need to be excluded  as well as familyid_Test  contains the family_id that need to be excluded , did you got me , now i think it's clear thanks a lot

Comment: Oh ok, then just exclude that - I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understood from your question, you can `innerjoin` both `range_id_Test` and `familyid_Test` with `newArticlesGold` and you should get your desired output as following (you can see that I have changed to column names of `range_id_Test` and `familyid_Test` tables.

```
val range_id_Test = newArticlesGold.select("range_id".as("range_id_1")).except(article_ranges.select("id").distinct())

val familyid_Test = newArticlesGold.select("family_id".as("family_id_1")).except(article_family.select("id").distinct())

val addedData = newArticlesGold.join(range_id_Test, $"range_id" =!= range_id_Test("range_id_1"))
    .join(familyid_Test, $"family_id" =!= familyid_Test("family_id_1"))
    .select(newArticlesGold.columns.map(col): _*)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.